# Почему "Россия" пишется с двумя С?

Tags: орфография, этимология, топонимика

Почему "Россия" пишется с двумя С, в то время как Русь - с одной? В чем разница?

Answer (score 9):

Добавлю - и частично возражу.
Церковнославянский здесь абсолютно ни при чем, появление слова Россия относят к XVI веку, в церковнословянском оно не могло возникнуть ранее чем в русском. А вот с греческим интересная штука происходит. 
По-гречески никакого удвоенного С там нет: Ρωσία (вопреки Фасмеру). При этом во времена Ивана Грозного написание следовало греческому оригиналу - с одной С.
Появление удвоенного С относят ко времени Петра Первого. Встречается объяснение, что удвоение С произошло под влиянием слова "русский", где второе С действительно от суффикса, но малоубедительно. Рискну предположить, что удвоение С связано с немецко-голландским влиянием (Петр не разделял голландцев и немцев как нации), и в немецком это удвоение С несёт фонетическую нагрузку: одинарное С озвончалось бы.

Answer (score 3):

В древнерусских летописях название народа - "русь" ("русин" в ед. числе), которое иногда используется и для обозначения страны. Но также страну называют в летописях "Русьская земля", что по отношению именно к стране корректнее. Таким образом, вторая "с" образуется из суффикса "-ск"/"-ст", образующего прилагательные от слова "русь": русь-ск-ая, например. "О" действительно заменяет "у" в греческом варианте - "Росия".
То, что в летописях не было второй "с", - ложь. Самая древняя из дошедших рукописей - лаврентьевская (1377 г.) содержит прилагательные как с одной, так и с двумя "с":

- "Руская земля" (л.1 об.)
- "море Руское" (л.3 об.)
- "рускаго князя" (л.6 об.)
- "людье рустии" (л.11 об.)
- "Русьскую землю" (л.50 об.)
- "самовластец Русьстей земли" (л.51)
- "князь русьскый" (л.54 об.)
- "земле Русьстей" (л.58)
- "русьскым именемь" (л.78)
- "землю Русскую" (л.101 об.)
- "князи русские" (л.103 об.)
- "Русскую землю" (л.169)

Сканы этой рукописи можно найти здесь: [Лаврентьевская летопись. 1377. Просмотр страниц рукописи | expositions.nlr.ru](http://expositions.nlr.ru/LaurentianCodex/_Project/page_Show.php)

Answer (score 0):

РАССЕЯ-ны, РАССЕЯ-не. Способ расселения славянских племён многочисленными политически обособленными родами: "дворы" рассеяны всюду по Приднепровью.

Повесть временных лет описывает форму колонизации земель восточными славянами: «живяху кождо с своим родом и на своих местех, владеюще кождо родом своим». У В.О.Ключевского в "Курсе Русской истории" говорится об этом же: как она /Повесть/ рассаживает по равнине всех этих полян, древлян, волынян, северян, радимичей, вятичей, кривичей, поломан, дреговичей, славян новгородских... По распадении союза под руководством волынян восточные славяне разделились на отдельные колена и каждое племя выбрало себе особого царя... Этому преданию отвечает известие, что после Кия с братьями род их начал держать княжение у полян, а у древлян было своё княжение, у дреговичей своё и т. д.